# SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition Not Connectable

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition but its not starting any network server. There is nothing listening on the default SS port (1433). I cannot connect to it with any db tool.

SSMS can connect but that's it. Is there something I need to configure to get it to start a network server? I went through the configuration tool and enabled TCP including choosing a NIC (address). That did nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
spid17s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 51838].
spid17s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 51838].
Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 64511].
Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 64511].
```

Why the weird ports?  Is this specific to this edition?
And you have to go to the error log to find out which port its using.

Answer (score 1):

The only required steps are:

1. Enable TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Restart SQL Server
3. Open the Windows Firewall

The SQL Server log will record the IP address and port it is listening on during startup with an entry like:

```
Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
```

Comment: Its using some weird port. Its ignoring the configuration.  And even when you use that port its still mis-behaving. Can't create a db.

Comment: I just tested this on a new Azure VM.  You must have installed a named instance.  A default instance of SQL 2017 Developer Edition will listen on port 1433 just like every other edition (including Express).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that 2017 Dev Edition acts like the Free Edition and uses random ports. But you can change it.  See link below.  Argh!
[How to Configure SQL Server to Use a Specific Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port)