# Trouble connecting to a remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, networking, database-connection

I have a bit of a head-scratcher here. I have two development PCs on my network behind the same firewall. One can connect to a remote SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio, the other cannot. I can connect using two different methods, one using an encrypted VPN and the other with a direct connection. Both computers are running Windows 10.

I have turned off the Windows Firewall on the computer that fails to rule it out and it had no effect.

I have ran a port scanner on both computers to test both connection methods, the one that connects shows that port 1433 is open on the remote computer the other does not.

Clearly the communication is failing at some point, but I've run out of ideas of things to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207948/sql-server-2017-developer-edition-not-connectable ?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the remote server via IP address? Sounds like the Windows 10 machines are talking to different DNS servers and may be returning different (or no) IP addresses for the remote server's FQDN.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Alexander,both servers I am attempting to connect to are production servers and one of the PCs can connect so I know they're both listening.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes, I should have mentioned that I only use IP addresses to connect to, never the named instance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: When the hosting company originally set up our VPS, they IP locked the access. I modified the rule to add my additional IP and everything is working now.